# How to write code to run once and only once

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm looking for a way to write code such that when a program is first started up, this segment of code runs once and only once.  If the program is closed and started up again, the code will not run again.  It would only run again if the entire application was uninstalled and resinstalled from scratch.

A config file or flag in a database is not a solution for this problem.

I read something somewhere (which i can't seem to find) about some way to basically run something once and it could then essentially compile a variable into the binary to be used forever and ever.

Thanks for any help I can get on this!

Comment: read about selfmodifying executable files + additional security checks, like registry modification, temporary files, sending info over to some web server and checking while starting-up, logging how many times application was executed etc.

Comment: I haven't thought about doing it in the install.  It may be possible to do it there, but I would have to look into it.  Good point!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are going to have to store state somewhere. There are lots and lots of places you could do so, and the technique used in each case is different:

1. In a config file (which you specifically disavow)
2. In the registry, which some may consider out of fashion, but is certainly an option.
3. On an off machine web site, a server you write, or a web site or something like that, however this requires an infrastructure, and a network ping.
4. You can do something like you suggest, where you dynamically recompile a DLL or a program, and adjust the source code. This isn't much different than a config file -- except that the config file is an executable -- it also has the disadvantage that many times restricted users can't do that, and may not have write permssion where you want to store it (in Program Files for example.)

I am sure there are other ways too. However, like most programming problems you have to consider the trade offs, and determine which is right for you.

If you can offer more information and context (for example, why can't you just write it to a config file) perhaps we can help you better judge.

If it works for you, one simple solution might be to have the installer add a dummy file called, for example, neverrun.txt. When you run check for the existence of the file. If it is there, execute your code, then delete the file. That way a reinstall is needed to get that code executed.

However, there are a number of problems with this approach. It is not reliably secure (it is easy to establish the start state and recreate the file) and your users might not be able to delete a file in Program Files or where ever you dump it. We'd need more context to understand the underlying goals you have.

Comment: Right, so the reason I dont want to use a config file is mainly because I was hoping someone else had read about a way to compile code that will modify the executable once and never run again.  I couldn't remember where I read this.  Currently, we check a database to see if the current version of the program has been run once or not.

Comment: FWIW it isn't all that hard to recompile the binary (though you probably only want to recompile a tiny DLL unless you want all your source code deployed.) I don't know what your needs are in detail, but I find it hard to imagine a situation when this would be the right approach. But this might be due to my lack of imagination. See this link for dynamic compiles: http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/dynamicCode/DynamicCode.htm

Comment: An alternative to keeping a config file around is to have your installer drop a "first run" marker file, and have your application delete it once it's done that initial setup.

Comment: Like Mike said, you have to store state somewhere. It sounds like you really just want to make sure that state is unfeasibly difficult to un-set, so your users won't do it. This is dicey; if you don't trust your users (and you shouldn't if your users are not employees or otherwise bound by some enforceable CoC), then the state should not be stored anywhere on their machine, because anything that can be changed can have that change tracked and undone.

Comment: Thats a great link, and exactly the information I was looking for!  I guess my communication skills in the subject matter are lacking...haha.  Thank you!

Comment: Another option is to store your state information in an ADS stream relative to the file. Technically its another file but its generally a "super hidden" file that no one can see. It won't work on a FAT32 system but pretty much everything now is NTFS.

Answer (score 4):

Okay, couldn't resist, here's a version that writes to an ADS stream.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        private static string ADS_Part = "RunOnceFlag";
        private static uint FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS = 0x2000000;
        private static uint CREATE_ALWAYS = 2;
        private static uint OPEN_EXISTING = 3;
        private static uint FILE_SHARE_READ = 0x1;
        private static uint GENERIC_READ = 0x80000000;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (IsFirstEverRun())
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("First run");
                SetRunOnce();
            }
            else
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("I've been run at least once!");
            }
        }
        private static bool IsFirstEverRun()
        {
            //Current running EXE (assumes not being loaded from another program)
            string P = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName;
            string ADSFile = P + ":" + ADS_Part;

            //Try opening the ADS
            using (var FH = CreateFile(ADSFile, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, IntPtr.Zero, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS, IntPtr.Zero))
            {
                //Return whether its a valid handle or not
                return FH.IsInvalid;
            }

        }
        private static void SetRunOnce()
        {
            //Current running EXE (assumes not being loaded from another program)
            string P = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName;
            string ADSFile = P + ":" + ADS_Part;

            //Create the ADS. We could write additional information here such as date/time first run or run counts, too
            using (var FH = CreateFile(ADSFile, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, IntPtr.Zero, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS, IntPtr.Zero)){}
        }


        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle CreateFile(string lpFileName,
            uint dwDesiredAccess,
            uint dwShareMode,
            IntPtr lpSecurityAttributes,
            uint dwCreationDisposition,
            uint dwFlagsAndAttributes,
            IntPtr hTemplateFile);
    }
}
```

Comment: hmmm, this is also an interesting alternative worth looking into.  You are right, it is technically a file, but it might be hard enough to maliciously alter this that it will be fine for my purposes.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to keep a resource around, like a file or a registry value somewhere to indicate to your program that the code has already been run and shouldn't be re-run. You can then check for this file/value at startup, and whenever you want to force the code to run again delete the file/value.

Examples:

- Temporary File in your program's app settings directory. (Note: Your uninstaller would have to clean this up)
- Registry Setting in HKLM / HKCU. (Note: Once again, cleaned up by registry)
- Change to your `app.config` or `web.config` (Note: This would not require uninstall cleaning as the normal uninstall process should delete the config file too, may not survive a dirty uninstall by the user just deleting files).

But this should probably be done in your install/uninstall step.

Answer (score 1):

Not seen in the answers so far, and although this is an old question let me add one more option to your list:

- Cheat with a Windows Service. Every time your application is started, it tries to install the service. If the service is already installed, it won't install the service again. Now you can choose to add extra functionality in the service itself (run it on startup of the system, require it to be running by your app, or even change the program to start from the service instead of from the original shortcut).

Depending on your needs, this may be a viable solution. What you are actually doing here is changing the state of your program on first run and on subsequent runs, you run different code:

```
if(!serviceInstalled)
{
    CodeThatRunsOnceAndOnlyOnce();
    InstallService();
}
```

But, unless you add functionality through the service, an easier solution, and the de facto solution in my opinion, is by saving state in the registry. If you want to hide it from deletion, obfuscate the registry entry.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed your tag is for both Asp.Net and Winforms, kinda strange to have something like this in Asp.Net, but why not just add this to your installer package?

Comment: Do not post questions to the Poster in an answer. This is what comments are for.

Answer (score 0):

In a WinForms app, call the code from your app start up code, in an ASP.NET app, call it from the `Application_Start()` handler in Global.asax. (I have no idea how your app can be both.)

Comment: He's not looking for a run once per execution, he's looking for a run once per install.

Answer (score 0):

Configure project setting, and set a variable as a flag...

you can do that by right click on project node, and go to properties, and setting section,
add a new string variable

and access it by: .setting.defaults.
i think...

and also to set it, after set your variable, you need to call save()

Answer (score 0):

you may have it written in a script, so after installing the app, the script is run and then removed.
or have a mini app that you manually run, either after the first install or whenever you want to reinitialize your app. this way you can restore a fresh install by running the mini app.